# Youtube delay auto start video

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

There is anyway to delay the auto start of a youtube video for example:" 20seconds, after page loads?"

Here is the example just with the auto start:

http://jsfiddle.net/qbqEA/

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not perfect solution but it works,

```
<iframe class="delayed" width="486" height="273" frameborder="0" data-src="__url__" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

note that I used data-src instead of 'src'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('iframe.delayed').attr('src', 
                                     $('iframe.delayed').attr('data-src')); 
    }, 20000);
}
```

It will load iframe 20 seconds after page loads. 
see my fork: http://jsfiddle.net/WswGV/

Comment: Understand not the perfect:) Thanks very much... just looking other way to do with but javascript to simulate a click after 20 seconds. Not to hide youtube gui from the user.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues then how about it? starts with autoplay=0 and replace src with autoplay=1 after 20 secs?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, can try after .. now trying to use javascript to insert the iframe , and use play event..probably the best solution.

Do you try that solution replacing the src ? No need to refresh dom?

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues I tried changing src after 20 secs and it worked. It doesn't refresh whole dom but inside the iframe. If you make same sized transparent div over the iframe and catch click event, you might accomplish 98% of what you want to do.

Comment: but 100% perfect solution is always using proper API call: http://code.google.com/intl/ko/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

Comment: is there a way to do same thing for vimeo's video in iFrame ? I tried this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to use YouTube.API with Javascript functionality.

```
 // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    setTimeout(function() {
        player.playVideo();
    }, 20000);
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {    
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
          height: '315',
          width: '560',
          videoId: 'I_V_kIzKKqM'
        }); 
    }
```

I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

The link to the IFrame YouTube API above is obsolete, I think, but here's one I found today:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Wish I'd read that a long time ago.

To excerpt from the example there, I would suggest that you detect the player being downloaded and ready, then set a timer for the desired number of seconds (20 in your case, I think), and then play the video.

---v

Answer (score 0):

Using https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference this will add a 10 second delay before the video automatically starts:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }, 10000);
  }

  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var frame = jQuery('.embed-responsive iframe');
    var src = frame.attr('src');
    setTimeout(function(){ frame.attr('src', src+'?autoplay=1'); }, 20000);
});
```