# Delay YouTube autoplay with 20 seconds

Tags: html, youtube-api

Is it possible to delay the autoplay of an `iframe` embeded YouTube player?

This is the the embed code I have:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iejOAPyooXs?wmode=transparent&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube delay auto start video](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8669702/2065237)

Answer (score 2):

Updated my answer to a better one using youtube player API for more option and dynamic output. It has many option to select and you could easily control it using Javascript. I hope this could help. Credits to @wasikuss posted answer.

```
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    setTimeout(function() {
        player.playVideo();
    }, 20000);
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {    
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
          height: '315',
          width: '560',
          videoId: 'iejOAPyooXs'
        }); 
    }
```

Reference https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: OK, thanks for the idea, I will actually try both of the solutions, but I'm pretty much sure that this is simpler, after I remake it with JavaScript.

Comment: No problem. Given that user can chose to play the video or wait it autoplay but it's depends on what you need. Glad to help. :)

Comment: but if user clicks play button himself, then video will be restarted due to `src` change

Comment: Updated answer, hopefully it could help

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to facilitate the delay.  Initially display just the video's thumbnail on the page.  In the JavaScript, wait for 20 seconds and then replace the preview with the video iframe.

This other post describes how to show just the thumbnail: [Youtube Video Thumbnail with Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2068344/2065237).

Answer (score 0):

Sildoreth's solution has one pitfall: user cannot play video himself.
More properly solution is to use YouTube IFrame API ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference ). After 20s just check video state ( `player.getPlayerState()` ) and if it is `video cued` ( `5` ) call `player.playVideo()`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wasikuss/1eg1w6dj/)