# how to start youtube video with autoplay after 10 sec of page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, youtube

Hello I want to start youtube video with autoplay after 10 seconds when the page load is completed. Is there any way to do this jQuery or javascript. I want to do this in a wordpress website.
the development site link:-

http://www.mediationadvantage.com/ (the video on left side need to be started)

Please give some idea or show some example on jsfiddle.

Thanks

Comment: Check out this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669702/youtube-delay-auto-start-video

Comment: YouTube has an API to control the player. Google took 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of YouTube parameters is autoplay if you set `autoplay = 1` The video will play automatically when the player loads and the default is `0` like this one

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

so my idea is to add this parameter `autoplay=1` to link but after 10s using the setTimeout function, wokring here

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var url = $('iframe').attr('src')
  url = url+'?autoplay=1';
  $('iframe').attr('src', url)
}, 2000); // 2000 = 2s, 10s= 10000
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

See this [PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWERdK)

Comment: thanks man it worked out

Answer (score 0):

You may add the embeding frame without any query parameters.

```
<iframe id="videoframe" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EuaYIttIowY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then you can create a function in javascript to change the property 'src' of the iframe tag

```
function autoPlayVideo() {
  var videoframe = document.getElementById('videoframe');
  videoframe.src = videoframe.src + '?rel=0&autoplay=1';
}
```

and then you can just add a simple line to set the timeout for 10 sec

```
setTimeout(autoPlayVideo(), 10000);
```

Please see this in working mode in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asim_Khan/15d7v4gx/)

Comment: thanks man you code also worked

Comment: Feeling confused ! why my answer got -1 while it also worked lolx