# How to delay autoplay in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, autoplay

I have a wordpress site and in front page I want to play a video when the site is loaded. But I want the video to play after 30 second the site is loaded. That means when the site is loaded for 30 seconds it will show video thumbnail and then it will play automatically. How can this be done?

Comment: Are you self-hosting your video or embed from another resource (youtube/Vimeo) ?

Comment: No,It's embed from youtube.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669702/youtube-delay-auto-start-video
I found a solution, you can try this.